# Unable to connect Windows Hyper-V to a server

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I am trying to set up Hyper-V on my Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit 8GB RAM  machine.

[Win10 E 64bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tAxY.jpg)

I have enabled hardware virtualization in the BIOS.

I am a member of the Hyper-V admin group.

I have activated the Windows Features:

[features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BoO6.jpg)

Vmms does run (although it shuts down after 10 mins or so):

[vmms running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVZOL.jpg)

As you can see, none of the other Hyper-V related services are running. They will not start when I attempt to start them. When I try it from Services they claim the service did not respond in a timely fashion, but no human perceptible amount of time elapses before they fail. They also generate a message saying that they started and then stopped:

[started then stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj5lX.jpg)

Hyper-V manager will start, but there are no servers visible or accessible:

[Hyper-V manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaXgD.jpg)

If I try to connect to one, it says "object not found":

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwZGP.jpg)

If I use Hyper-V Quick Create in an attempt to make a server, I get a phantom error, and it closes without trace when I select OK (even though its NOT "OK"):

[quick create unknown error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFGbO.jpg)

I have also done the corresponding above functions via command line from PowerShell as administrator, with similar results.

In the event logs corresponding to these attempts I find these entries for every service:
-The Hyper-V  Service service failed to start due to the following error: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

-A timeout was reached (60000 milliseconds) while waiting for the Hyper-V  Service service to connect. (note: it happens instantly, not after a minute)

What am I doing wrong? Why cant I create or access a server?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it working. As I mentioned above, the only Hyper-V related service I could get running was vmms, and you need vmcompute as well. It was (apparently) being blocked by something called Control Flow Guard.

Control Flow Guard is accessed through Start->Settings->Update & Security->Windows-Security->App & Browser Control->Exploit Protection Settings->Program Settings.

Scroll down to vcompute.exe, select EDIT, scroll down to Control Flow Guard, then UN-select override system settings.

Once I saved that, I was able to start both services and then Hyper-V Manager just started working. Thanks to those who might have been researching it.